# Need a specific field in FME KMZ to shapefile conversion

Tags: shapefile, convert, fme-form, kmz

I am converting a KMZ to shapefile and need to see a field called "Type Name", but it is not in any of the shapefiles' attribute tables. [image]

I have every name exposed in Format Attributes in the Reader and the reader's User Attributes are blank:

[image]

All the fields that show up in the attributes table are listed in the writer's User Attributes tab and I have tried it with Automatic and Dynamic selected: 
[image]

Also, it's strange that none of the fields have any real data. Every record in most of them is either blank or 0, and the others have meaningless constants. 
Am I doing what I need to do to in the conversion to see all the fields in this KMZ?

Comment: "Type Name" is not a valid dBase field name (spaces are forbidden)

Comment: I'm told, "it's something like 'Type Name'." As shown above in the Feature Type dialog box, "kml_type_name" is not in the attributes list.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the KML type, then that's the FME format attribute kml_name. You have it exposed in the reader, but then you need to connect it to something in the writer for it to get written.

Best solution is to use Manual for the output schema and add a new attribute (such as kmltype).

Then use an AttributeManager to rename the incoming kml_name to kmltype on the output.

Otherwise, can you see this attribute if you open up the KMZ in the FME Data Inspector? If you can't see it there then it's not going to come through the reader in Workbench. At that point perhaps open up the KML file in a text editor (the KMZ should simply be a zip file that you could extract the KML file from) and see if you can actually see it inside the file.

Other things you could do are to try the Scan Schema parameter on the reader (when you add the reader it should be set to Yes), and if that fails turn on the Verbose Logging parameter on the reader (which may give more info about what is going on).

Comment: Every feature in kml_name has NULL as the value. I see a field named kml_type in Data Inspector, though. I am a bit confused how to use AttributeManager because it would output to the writer. But the writer is where I would rename the field so AttributeManager could rename it. How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Where you have the option to Automatic/Manual/Dynamic click in the next blank space at the bottom of the list of attributes and enter your new attribute name. Then in the AttributeManager just find the attribute you've exposed on the input, and set its "Output Attribute" name to the attribute name you just added on the output.

Comment: I ran the AttributeManager transformer on the Placemark feature and got no output. (Maybe I did it wrong, as I put the AttrMgr between the reader and the Reprojector transformer. But I now realize the field I was using is just a useless fme field - fme_type - and its value is "fme_point". kml_name = "NULL" and kml_type, which I only see in Data Inspector when I select a point. kml_type = "kml_point". So I have no idea which field to run the AttributeManager on. Scan Schema has always been set to Yes. I ran it again with Verbose Logging = 'Yes' and without AttrMgr and again got no output. ...

Comment: However, I looked in the html code of the output and saw the things I am interested in... Field named TYPE_NAME and values "THEORETICAL SPLICE" and "SPLICE_CLOSURE_ID".  [code]<td>TYPE_NAME</td>
<td>THEORETICAL SPLICE</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">
<td>SPLICE_CLOSURE_ID</td>
<td>&lt;Null&gt;</td>[/code]

Comment: HTML tags, eh? That looks like it might get stored inside the description tag of the KML. Is that the parent tag of this section? If so expose the kml_description attribute in FME and use the HTMLExtractor transformer to get the data out of it. I'm not too well versed in CSS but I think if you put "td" (without the quotes) into the CSS Selector field and then set the Return Format to List Attribute, then you'll be able to see that HTML split up into its components. Then I'd suggest a ListIndexer transformer to get the values you want.

Comment: I ran it with the HTMLExtractor and got 71 errors, reran it after selecting 'Continue' in case the HTMLExtractor rejects something. This time it ran successfully but produced no shapefiles. The following is copied from the Translation Log: "Attribute(encoded: UTF-16LE): `kml_parent' has value `kml_id_doc_1.1'
Attribute(encoded: UTF-16LE): `kml_parent_type' has value `Document'". Does that answer your question about the parent tag?

Comment: It seems to a problem with what I am using for the CSS Selector: "HTMLExtractor_3: <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "folder\dw_working\kmzs\06212019shps3" ". That is the folder I am trying to write the shapefiles to. I have td in that field and List Attribute in Return Format. I have $(SourceDataset_OGCKML) in HTML Input and kml_description in HTML Content. I have $(DestDataset_ESRISHAPE) in Target Attribute. Should I take this issue to the FME Safe support forum?

Comment: I think it would be useful to contact the Safe support team. Then you can supply them your KML dataset in private and let them take a look. See safe.com/support Sorry we couldn't figure it out on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly likely you will have to dig deeper and expose the **Format Attributes**...

There can be many for kml but a good start is to expose  the kml_description/raw_text/document attributes.

[image]

Here is an example.

Comment: As stated above, I am exposing every Format Attribute in both the reader and writer.

Comment: use the AttributeExposer Transformer after this step

Comment: I added that transformer and connected it to the Placemark reader and, regardless if I select Import from Attribute names or Import from Attribute values, the list of attributes to import is blank.

Comment: it might not be in placemark there maybe style or other kml features that need to be used. do you have a link to the the kml?

Comment: Sorry, there's no link to it. Placemark has 5878 features and all the other features (e.g., Style, Document, ...)  combined have 4. I still tried them, though, but got the same result.